# Finding a value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find the best way to find a value in an array:

The value of `$this->school_degree` is retrieved from the Facebook Graph API.  For the sake of this example, its value could be any (but only one of the following):

- Masters of Science in Computer Science
- Masters in Computer Science
- Computer Science
- MBA

So my natural inclination was to do this:

```
 function EXPLODETEST () {
       $explode_degree = explode(" ", $this->school_degree);
       echo "$explode_degree[0]";
       echo "$explode_degree[1]";
       echo "$explode_degree[2]";
       echo "$explode_degree[3]";
       echo "$explode_degree[4]";
       echo "$explode_degree[5]";
       echo "$explode_degree[6]";
       }
```

At which point I'd have to create a really long if or statement to search each offset for the words `computer science`.

The endgame is to echo one statement if they're mastering in CS and echo another statement if they're not. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why explode it?  Just search the original string.  Try [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos).  `strpos($this->school_degree, 'Computer Science') !== FALSE`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the array looks like?

Comment: @MrGlass - Erm, he did. He's creating it with `explode` and shows you what the possible source strings are.

Comment: So `$this->school_degree` is a string, which he is then turning into an array?

Comment: @MrGlass: `explode(" ", $this->school_degree)`  http://php.net/explode

Comment: I know what explode is. The phrasing of his question made me think `$this->school_degree` was being given to him as an array. which didn't make sense, granted, but thats why i asked.

Comment: Exploding a string on a space, then searching the resultant array for an element that contains a space is rather contradictory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the degree always contains the words "Computer Science" could you not just search for that text in the string?

```
if (strpos($this->school_degree, "Computer Science") !== false)
{
    echo "Mastering in CS";
}
else
{
    echo "Not Mastering in CS";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't always contain the words Computer Science, they could be getting a master's in something else.

Comment: @mattrmclaren: Hence `echo "Not Mastering in CS"`.  What's the issue?

Comment: @mattrmclaren I meant for those who study Computer Science. You want to distinguish those who study CS from those who don't right? So if those who are studying CS always have "Computer Science" in the title of their degree, you can use that to distinguish.

Comment: If you could up vote this question it would be sincerely appreciated.